# How to find the exact number of a single letter in a string of characters in R?

Tags: string, r, search, character

I have a string of characters.

```
c = c("a", "about", "base", "base", "h2o", "h", "yes", "a", "c", "h", "d")
```

I need to find out how many times a specific single letter, e.g. "a", "c", "h", "d", are repeated in the strings. I have tried

```
grep("a", c, fixed=TRUE, useBytes=TRUE)
```

But it will gives all the positions where "a" appears, including "about" and "base". I have also tried

```
match("a", c)
```

Sadly, it only gives the position of the 1st match and ignores the following matches.

How can get all the position of "a", which should be 1 and 8?

Comment: Does `which(x == "a")` get you what you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're just looking for `table` and `which`:

```
String <- c("a", "about", "base", "base", "h2o", "h", "yes", "a", "c", "h", "d")
table(String)
# String
#     a about  base     c     d     h   h2o   yes 
#     2     1     2     1     1     2     1     1 

which(String == "a")
# [1] 1 8

nchar(String)
#  [1] 1 5 4 4 3 1 3 1 1 1 1

table(String[nchar(String) == 1])
# 
# a c d h 
# 2 1 1 2
```

Comment: @TylerRinker, it's too late where I am to do any mind reading right now :-)

Comment: I wrote a app for that `sample(c(T, F), 1)` :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could just alter you regular expression within grep

```
v = c("a", "about", "base", "base", "h2o", "h", "yes", "a", "c", "h", "d")
grep("^a$", v)
#[1] 1 8
length(grep("^a$", v))
#[1] 2
```